# How to open archives in 7zip File Manager using command line options?

Tags: windows, command, command-line-interface, 7zip

colleges.
I stuck with trying to open zip archive via command line in 7z GUI.

I have found in documentation that
-7z.exe does not have command to open file in new window.
-Also i did not found command line parameters for 7zFM.exe and 7zG.exe

Does anyone know how to solve this problem or make a workaround for my case.

Here described how to use 7z.exe http://sevenzip.osdn.jp/chm/cmdline/ but not any word  about opening archive in GUI.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

I was able to open a 7zip archive in a new window using the command

```
7zfm archiveName.7z
```

Setting 7zFM as the default program to open .7z file extensions will also open the archive in a new window after double-clicking on it.